# Are mutagens permanent?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Once I alter one of my abilities with a Mutagen, is it like equipment where I can go back later and switch it out for a better one?  Or is it a permanent change to that ability that I'll keep for the rest of this playthrough?

Comment: This is a good question. Makes me glad I upgraded my first ability with a Critical Effects mutagen rather than a lesser mutagen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mutagens cannot be reversed nor replaced. Once applied they cannot be upgraded either.

So if you have a lesser version of some mutagen, you might want to wait for the greater version and sell everything until then.

Personally, I find it a bad design decision.
It should at least allow you to upgrade from lesser to basic to greater on the same type of mutagen, but that's just me.

Comment: This game is full of bad design decisions, all offset by how amazing the combat is.

Comment: Do note that Greater Mutagens can drop from the beginning of the game, so it's not even like you miss out on much by waiting for them in the first place.