# Which abilities contain mutagen slots?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Which abilities in The Witcher 2 contain Mutagen slots?

Does the level of points invested in the ability affect the availability of mutagen slots?

Comment: [Related question on how to use mutagens](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/how-to-use-mutagens-in-the-witcher-2) and [on whether mutagens are permanent](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22651/are-mutagens-permanent)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

List of talents containing mutagen slots:

**Training tree:**

- Arrow redirection
- Fortitude

**Swordsmanship tree:**

- Invincible
- Combat Acumen
- Whirlwind

**Magic tree:**

- Enhanced Yrden Sign
- Sense of Magic
- Control over the Power

**Alchemy tree:**

- Condensation
- Metathesis
- Berserker
- Mutant
- Amplification

You only need one point invested in a talent to mutate it.

Comment: I've made this CW, feel free to add any talents witch mutagen slots you find.

Comment: I know the one at the top-right of the first tree (it gives you extra vigor and vigor regen, I think) has a mutagen slot, but I'm at work now so I can't look up the name.

Comment: @StrixVaria I added it. From the ones we have so far the slots seem to be at the end of each tree.

Comment: I added the five Alchemy skills.  Note that this is one of the advantages of specializing in Alchemy - more options for mutagens, which makes sense.  And you are correct, they're generally at the end of the trees.

Comment: Now a new question: What's the greatest number of mutagen slots you could possibly get? What's the level cap, 30 something, I think?

Answer (score 1):

Mutagen: Hit 'C' key to open character screen.  Click on 'Training', look at the tiny circle [top right] of the top 2 talents. Right click on talent, select your mutagen and then apply.

Same applies to 'Swordsmanship' talents, although it'll be quite awhile until you reach the end of the tree where the mutagen slots appear.

For 'enhancing' swords and armor that have those tiny slots [top right of item], you'll need to go to a craftsman. 
I'm not sure if you can remove or replace one enhancement for another, once applied to item.

I have found 'Critical Effect Mutagens' that will help boost your 'Critical Effects' [i.e. bleeding,poison etc.] chance.  You can find what % chance you have of activating these Critical Effects within your 'character' ['C'] screen.  Now press 'Enter' key to access your attributes, then click on 2nd tab at top right.  At the bottom left, you'll see Critical Effects percentages listed.  Bear in mind, you must have your sword drawn to have its effects shown on this screen.  From there you can use 'Brown Oil' for example in battle via Inventory screen dragging to weapon, or prior to boost that bleeding Critical Effect chance by 30%.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Under magic:

*Enhanced Yrden Sign*, *Sense of Magic*, and *Control over the Power* have slots.

Comment: I want to edit to correct for spelling... but do you mean Yrden or Aard?

Comment: @Raven The answerer "answered" in an edit