# Witcher 2 reset skill points / skills guide

Tags: the-witcher-2

Is it possible to reset skill points in Witcher 2 ? If not (still nice to know), what is the best way to spend the skills. Not that you invest in only one tree but in all of them. Can you max all skill trees. What are the most rewarding skills that should be taken first ?

Also how important is the training skill tree ?

Comment: Presumably the downvote is because you have about 6 questions in here, most of which are already answered on this site.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz It partly answers thequestion. Mainly how do I put the skills to best use. Since it may not be possible to re-spec at all, or only once if possible, knowing bad/under utilized skills beforehand would be nice. Otherwise it is becoming a drag adapting to those skills.

Comment: The dupe refers to the 'main' question as evinced by your title. Go through our Witcher 2 tag and you'll find the rest of your answers. Please don't make me regret voting to close this as a dupe rather than Too Broad or Unclear What You're Asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to reset the skill tree by finding [the operator](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Operator) in chapter 3, this is the only opportunity in the entire game to do so and requires specific actions from the previous chapters to set up.

It is impossible to max all the skill trees since the maximum level is 35.

The training tree is not too important but it does offer [2 mutagen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/which-abilities-contain-mutagen-slots) slots.

As for the most rewarding skills, that depends entirely on your play style.  You can go full swordsmanship, full signs, or full alchemy, or a mix of the three.

Comment: To add I found an excellent guide to the skills here at http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/faqs/63730